# Train the neural network with negative lokelihood for regression

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to train the simple feedforward neural network using the negative-likelihood function to estimate the uncertainty for the regression task. My neural network outputs the mean and variance as two labels and I have written the custom loss function as follows:

```
def nll_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    epsilon = 1e-6
    mean = y_pred[:,0] # mean
    sigma_sq = y_pred[:,1] # variance
    sigma_sq_sp = K.log(1 + K.exp(sigma_sq)) + 1e-06 # softplus on the variance
    nll_loss =  0.5 * K.mean(K.log(sigma_sq_sp + epsilon) + K.square(y_true - mean) / (sigma_sq_sp + epsilon))
    
    return nll_loss

inp = Input(shape=(1,))
x = Dense(10, activation="relu")(inp)
x = Dense(20, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dense(30, activation="relu")(x)
output = Dense(2, activation="linear")(x)

model = Model(inp, output)

model.compile(loss=nll_loss, optimizer='adam')

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50)
```

My `x_train` and `y_train` has (200,) shape, meaning that a scalar feature and labels (and 200 examples). Is it correct to use the slicing `y_pred[:,0]` and `y_pred[:,1]` to extract the first and second labels from the output layer?

My model gets trained for few epochs and then the loss is `nan`. Am I doing anything wrong in computing the loss function? Is it ok to have `y_true` and `y_pred` to have a different shape?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem was with the computation of Softplus activation function:

```
sigma_sq_sp = K.log(1 + K.exp(sigma_sq)) + 1e-06
```

When I replace the above lines with the below code, it is working fine:

```
sigma_sq_sp = tf.keras.activations.softplus(sigma_sq)
```

Maybe, the inbuild Keras activation for softplus ensures stability.
Thank you.